# MVC model binding, Initial Model Missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In this instance I have two pages, in the post method of the first I return the view/viewmodel of the second like so :

```
    [HTTPPost]
    public Task<ActionResult> Page1(Page1Model model)
    {
        var Page2Model = GrabDataMethod(model);

        return View("Page2", Page2Model); //Point 1
    }

    [HTTPPost]
    public Task<ActionResult> Page2(Page2Model model //Point 2)
    {
        var updatedModel= RunFiltersMethod(model)

        return View(updatedModel);
    }
```

Now, in this case Page2 renders properly from (Point 1) with all values passed in above from the GrabDataMethod. However, when I POST for Page2 the Page2Model I receive at (Point 2) has none of the original entries, e.g. everything not modified directly by Page2 itself is null or default (in fact it seems the model from the post method is a new model entirely). I've made a horrible workaround for the time being, but I need a proper fix, is there any reason that this would be happening?

Page2 View Code

```
@model Mvc2013.Models.Page2Model
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page2", "Controller")) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Kendo().Chart(<!-- code removed, this is working -->)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prop1, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prop1)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prop2, new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop2, new { @class = "control-label"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prop2)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- This carries on similarly for lots more attributes -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: What is Page1Model? Page2Model is the same as Page1Model? If you are posting different models to the same action, this will not bind properly.

Comment: @Fals I was not clear about the two actions involved, made an update for hopeful clarity

Comment: Do you also have the view sample code which post to the Page2 action?

Comment: Could you post the view, there's something else wrong there!

Comment: Just a moment changing to names to protect the innocent and whatnot, the view will be posted momentarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the Beginform you should add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Something)` where the Something are the properties which you want back on the postback.

If you don't then the property values will be default values.

Comment: Well, that fixed my problem, I appreciate the assistance.